# pyautogui works fine when program run from Terminal but not in VSCode, AttributeError: dlsym(0x3a212e95c, objc_msgSendSuper_stret): symbol not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pyautogui

Trying to run a simple Python program using pyautogui in VSCode (just imports the package and clicks somewhere). Program runs fine when called from Terminal, but running it in VSCode produces the following error despite running the same python environment:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/***/Desktop/Solitaire/runner.py", line 1, in <module>
    import SolitaireSolver
  File "/Users/***/Desktop/Solitaire/SolitaireSolver.py", line 1, in <module>
    import time, pyautogui
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 249, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
    from rubicon.objc import ObjCClass, CGPoint
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rubicon/objc/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from . import api, collections, runtime, types
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rubicon/objc/api.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .runtime import (
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rubicon/objc/runtime.py", line 460, in <module>
    libobjc.objc_msgSendSuper_stret.restype = None
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 387, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 392, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(0x3a212e95c, objc_msgSendSuper_stret): symbol not found
```

I am on a MacBook Air M1, 2020 running Ventura 13.2.

VSCode version info:
Version: 1.77.3
Commit: 704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710
Date: 2023-04-12T09:19:37.325Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 22.3.0
Sandboxed: Yes

pyautogui version info:
Name: PyAutoGUI
Version: 0.9.53
Summary: PyAutoGUI lets Python control the mouse and keyboard, and other GUI automation tasks. For Windows, macOS, and Linux, on Python 3 and 2.
Home-page: https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui
Author: Al Sweigart
Author-email: al@inventwithpython.com
License: BSD
Location: /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: mouseinfo, pygetwindow, pymsgbox, pyobjc, pyobjc-core, pyscreeze, PyTweening
Required-by:

I was expecting the code to work since it works elsewhere. Tried googling the issue and found similar errors but not this exact one. Not sure what the error means.

Comment: any difference in `PATH` environment variable or cwd between the two environments?

Comment: nope, identical

Comment: I found [a similar issue in Github](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/420). If you try to upgrade to `pynput==1.7.6`, is it effective?